# Delayed Rewards in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I have an MDP where the rewards are delayed for six steps as follows:

The reward from action at time t is received when the action at time t+6 is taken.

The reward from action at time t+1 is received when the action at time t+7 is taken etc.

How can I modify Q-Learning or a variant of Q-Learning in order to handle delayed rewards?

Is there a model-free rl algorithm in general that handles delayed rewards?

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a new MDP which is the same as your old MDP, with the exception that the new state is actually the concatenation of (up to) $k+1$ states of your old MDP, where $k$ is the amount of delay.

In your new MDP, the reward from going from state $s$ to $s'$ is obtained by computing the reward for going from state $s_0$ to $s_0'$ in the original MDP, where $s_0$ gets the first "sub-state" in the concatenated state.

Our new MDP is indeed markov, and rewards are no longer delayed.

Comment: Thank you @shimao for your comment but I didn't understand exactly what you meant. The trajectories I have is as follows: 
S1, A1, S2, A2, S3, A3, S4, A4, S5, A5, S6, A6, S7, R1, A7, S8, R2, A8 R3 etc.

How can I compute actions A2-A6 if I do not have any rewards until then?

Comment: @gnikol an agent's actions should be dependent on the state -- not the reward received.